# CloudKit Predicate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, cloudkit

I am making a messaging application and as push notification service I am using CloudKit. The push notifications work probably wit the predicate 'TRUEPREDICATE', but the problem is if A sends a message to B, C gets a push notification too.My question now is how I can filter the predicate that only the person who gets a message gets a push notification.

```
 let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Message", predicate: predicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)

    let notification = CKNotificationInfo()
    notification.alertBody = "You have a new message!"
    notification.soundName = "default"

    subscription.notificationInfo = notification

    database.save(subscription) { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example a push notification would be triggered for each device the query subscription is setup on. If you want to correct this, you would need to modify your predicate to limit notifications to the current user/device.

For instance, if you are tracking a unique id for a specific user:

```
let userID = UUID().uuidString
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: ["recipient", userID])
```

In this example, "recipient" is the CloudKit field name.